# Best approach to eliminate duplicate objects in array

Tags: java, arrays, duplicates

I've a problem and need some help...

My object has a name, longitude and latitude. My problem is, that I've an array which has all the objects inside and now there are (nearly) duplicates.

That means long/lat are just nearly the same but definitely duplicates.

How can I filter them to get a list with unique objects? Here's what I've done so far...

```
public static Collection<Station> findDuplicates(Collection<Station> stations) {
    Collection<Station> uniqueList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Station firstStation : stations) {
        Station tempStation = firstStation;
        for (Station secondStation : stations) {
            //Check if distance of the stations is less than 25m then we assume it's the same and we are going to merge the stations
            if ((distanceFrom(firstStation.getLatitude(), firstStation.getLongitude(), secondStation.getLatitude(), secondStation.getLongitude()) < 25)) {
                tempStation = mergeStation(firstStation, secondStation);
            }
        }
    }
    //How to find/add unique stations to uniqueList   
    return uniqueList;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you may want to consider to use a `Set` instead of a `List` and override `equals(Object o)` for the `Station` class

Comment: I'm more into C# but doesn't java have something like custom IEquality comparer and Distinct call?

Comment: @vhr *Distinct call* in Java is like a *quarter pounder* in Europe :D

Comment: @fantaghirocco doesn't `Set` compare objects which are exactly the same? In my case I've different long/lat which has similar values but are the same? Or should it work?

Comment: Are you sure removing "nearly" identical objects is a good idea? Lets imagine 3 objects. The 1st is nearly identical to the 2nd. Same goes for the 2nd and 3rd. But at the same time 1st and 3rd aren't. What happens then? You remove 2nd only? Or maybe you remove 1st and 3rd and just keep the middle? What if you have a line of 500 dots like that - every two nearby dots are "nearly" identical but are not to any other. I don't think your strategy is good enough for removing noise (I assume that's what you're trying to do here)

Comment: @Amongalen I'd be very happy for a better strategy if you have a better idea! :)

Comment: Sadly I'm not really familiar with noise reduction algorithms, you'll have to search for them yourself. I can only see that your approach is a bit faulty. I think it might be kinda important what your application is and how accurate the results should be.

Answer (score 3):

Just use `Set` instead of `List` as follows:

```
public static Collection<Station> findDuplicates(Collection<Station> stations) {
    Set<Station> uniqueList = new HashSet<>();
    // rest of your code
}
```

However, for this solution to work properly it's important to override `equals` and `hashCode` for Station. Something like this:

```
    public class Station {
        private long latitude;
        private long longitude;

        Station(long latitude, long longitude) {
            this.latitude = latitude;
            this.longitude = longitude;
        }

        long getLatitude() {
            return latitude;
        }

        long getLongitude() {
            return longitude;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) {
                return true;
            }
            if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
                return false;
            }
            Station station = (Station) o;
            return latitude == station.latitude &&
                longitude == station.longitude;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return Objects.hash(latitude, longitude);
        }
    }
```

Comment: And if you want to keep the array original order, you can use a LinkedHashSet.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Collection<Station> findDuplicates(Collection<Station> stations) {
    Collection<Station> uniqueList = new ArrayList<>();
    uniqueList.Add(stations[0]); 
    for (Station station : stations) {
        //check if uniqueList contains station, if not add it to the uniqueList         
    }    
    return uniqueList;
}
```

Use this feature of java to find collection elements: [Java streams](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams-2177646.html)

Or iterate the uniqueList and use overriden Equals in your Station class 
    
    `@Override
    public boolean equals`

Answer (score 0):

Modify your `Station` class as [suggested by Zgurskyi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54593015/2656305.). Then you can just do this:

```
public static Collection<Station> findDuplicates(Collection<Station> stations) {
    Set<Station> unique = new HashSet<>();
    stations.forEach(unique::add);
    return unique;
}
```